# Is it possible to dynamically update if functions in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm using a state chart in combination with a schedule in Anylogic (see picture). The output of the schedule is equal to 1 during working hours and 0 otherwise. Now I want the transition from state1 to state2 to happen when the schedule is turning to 1 or is equal to 1(so otherwise wait until the working hours).

I have tried using an if statement

```
   if( main.plannerSchedule()==1 )(<perform action>)
```

However, by this method, the state transition only happens if the statement is true but doesn't wait for it to become true. Is there a way to constantly update the state transition or is there a "wait until" function that can solve this problem?

[image: State chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best let the schedule send a message to your statechart when it switches. This assumes that the statechart lives on the same agent type as the schedule. Write this code in the action code box of the schedule:

```
if (value==1) {
    statechart.fireEvent("go to state 2");
}
```

Obviously, your message transition needs to await the "go to state 2" message.

Note the `value` keyword. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling for more info on that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working in a small try out model. However, for some reason, I can't get it working in my more complex model. I think the reason is that the state chart is already activated by another message. Does this matter?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Do study the example models and help on understanding state charts. Also, please upvote the answer (up-arrow next to it) so others can find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote